# How to implement popup in custom visualization D3 components of Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I have created a custom visualization in Apache Superset. As visualization components are written in pure D3. I want to implement the popup functionality on click event.

I am facing issue to write React code in D3 custom components. Also, I want to access the redux store state inside D3 component. so need help to achieve this functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Rahul, I also want to create my own custom visualisation in Apache Superset. May you please guide me to implement it. I'm trying but didn't get any luck.

Comment: Hey Abhishek, for custom visualization in Superset, [Superset Visualization](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/6838) this link will help you out.